# Can't we access content from post variable in wordpress as normal php

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to write search in wordpress, what I did was created template page for one tab in wordpress site and add following form to it.

```
<?php  get_header(); ?>

            <div id="primary" class="site-content">
                <div id="content" role="main">

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php //get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
                        <?php// comments_template( '', true ); ?>

                <form name="input" action="" method="get"></br></br>
                    <input type="text" name="test" width="20" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

                </form>
                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>



                </div><!-- #content -->
            </div><!-- #primary -->

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then I tried to catch variable values from post array in other file created in drffernt directory.

There I tried to print the variable.

```
<?php echo $_POST["test"];?>
```

Though url shows something like `http://localhost/wordpress/skill/test.php?test=bbbbbbb`,
I get 404 error.
Can't I deal with word press as normal php web site?
If not what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: well since you are getting a 404, it means either your url path is wrong or there is some routing (like mod_rewrite,.htaccess if using apache) going on that is sending the browser to a non-existent file.

Comment: yes that is the reason. But I can't still print the value of variable. thanks

Comment: well with the url http://localhost/wordpress/skill/test.php?test=bbbbbbb the variable `test` is going to be in $_GET not $_POST

Comment: thanks, Is it ok to handle the content like this?

Comment: well wordpress should have internal framework API function that retrieves data for you (and hopefully sanitizing it for you. For instance Joomla (a different cms) uses something like JRequest::getInt("somevariable"), to get an integer named somevariable from post/get. You will have to look in the wordpress documentation to find out what wordpress uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can't understand: you wanted to add a "search function" to your site?
why not use the default?

[get search form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form)

and the code `<?php echo $_POST["test"];?>` won't work because there is not such thing as `test` on the page. and because this is your HTML form:

`<form name="input" action="" method="get">`

notice the: `method="get"` you can't say the form will use the method `get` and than use `Post` for taking the contents of the form.